# How to access array in outside while loop in fgetcsv

Tags: php, arrays, fgetcsv

I want to fetch all the contents of a csv file into an array so I used the `fgetcsv` function. It is working correctly, but when I want to return my array it is empty. The problem seems to be outside the while loop.

Here is my code:

```
$filepath="Data\";
$csvfile=array();    /* here i did declaration */

$csvfile=csvcontain($filepath);
print_r($csvfile);  /*prints empty array */

function csvcontain($filepath)
{
    foreach (glob($filepath."*."."csv") as $filename) 
    {
        $file_handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
        while (!feof($file_handle)) 
        {
            $csv=fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
            $csvfile=$csv;
        }
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $csvfile;
}
```

I am not getting where it is going wrong.

Comment: PHP does not have block scope, the variable is there perfectly fine. If it isn't, that means the loop has never been executed.

Comment: Close your file after opening it when you did all the read operations.
You are just closing the last opened file here (put it inside foreach after the while loop)

Comment: when i print in side while loop the data is coming in array..

Comment: @Koren i did.but still it is empty.

Comment: The code you have there has a parse error. You need an extra \ before the closing single quote when filepath is declared. I am sure that this is not the issue, but it would help if you would edit to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

csvfile is being overwritten, not added to on each iteration of the loop.

Try replacing `$csvfile=$csv;` with `$csvfile[]=$csv;`. This should add a new element to an array.